# Парсинг текста с помощью Simple Html Dom Parser

Tags: php, парсер

не производится парсинг текста в h3, пробовал несколько вариантов, как я понял проблема в значении index элемента

```
    <div class="photo">
      <div class="img">          
        <div class="p10">
          <a href="/upload/1.png"/></a></div>
            <h3>текст</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

первый вариант

```
include_once ('components/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('parser.html');
$tovar = $html->find('photo img ') as $tovar_img;
$tovar_img = $tovar->find('div.img p10 ', 0) as $tovar_p10;
$tovar_p10 = $tovar_img->find('div.p10 h3 ', 0) as $tovar_name;
echo $tovar_name;
```

второй вариант

```
include_once ('components/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('parser.html');
$tovar = $html->find('div.photo', 0) -> find('div.img') -> find('div.p10') -> find('div.h3') as $tovar_name;
echo $tovar_name;
```

третий вариант

```
include_once ('components/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('parser.html'); 
if(count($html->find('photo'))){
   foreach($html->find('div.photo div.img div.p10 div.h3') as $h3){
     echo $h3->plaintext.'<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Первый вариант не выдавал вам кучу ошибок?

Comment: выдавал 

     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_AS in

ссылался на 

    $tovar = $html->find('photo img ') as $tovar_img;

Comment: У меня ругался в другом месте. Странная конструкция: `$tovar = $html->find('photo img ') as $tovar_img;` Зачем тут `as`?

Comment: пробовал по очереди находить элементы  через предыдущий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы перепутали `str_get_html()` с `file_get_html()`

Нужно написать:

```
$html = file_get_html('parser.html');
```

тогда это вообще не нужно:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
```

или:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('parser.html');
```

**Дополнено**

Также чтобы найти нужный вам элемент достаточно написать так:

```
$tovar_name = $html->find('.photo .img h3', 0);
```

См также:

[How to create HTML DOM object?](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_create)

Comment: спасибо, но с 
     $html = file_get_html('parser.html');
тоже пробовал, без результатно

Comment: Очевидно файл не найден по указанному пути или нет прав на его чтение

Comment: @МаксимСоколенко Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу

Comment: если выводить весь html 
echo #html;
то всё показывает

Comment: А если так: `echo $html->find('h3', 0);` ?

Comment: увы но элемент h3 не один на странице

Comment: Но находит первый элемент? Если так, то пробуйте `echo $html->find('.photo .img .p10 h3', 0);` ?

Comment: попробовал - пустая страница

Comment: @МаксимСоколенко Значит путь к этому элементу неправильный.

Comment: @МаксимСоколенко Точно неправильный `echo $html->find('.photo .img h3', 0);` у `<div class="p10">` тег закрывается перед `<h3>`

Comment: извините за невнимательность получилось